# Проблемы сериализации NULL и String.Empty через подключенную службу

Tags: c#, xml, wsdl, сериализация

В проекте присутствует подключенная через wsdl-файл служба, с которой недавно возникли проблемы. После того, как мы стали использовать дополнительные поля возникла следующая проблема.
При попытке отправить пустые (null, string.Empty) значения строковых полей через подключенную службу появляются пустые теги вида:

```
<tag/>
```

Служба, к которой мы обращаемся, не принимает данные теги. При этом, если тег будет полностью отсутствовать, запрос пройдет успешно. Проблема с этими полями появилась после того, как мы стали передавать в них приходящие значения. (пробовали инициализировать поля разными способами, проблема остается)

Поля, которые мы заполняем находятся в сгенерированном файле Reference.cs.
Для данных полей отсутствуют поля *Specified, а их добавление бессмысленно, так как изменения смываются при первом же билде.

В файле службы проблемные поля выглядят примерно так.

```
<xsd:group name="Group">
    <xsd:annotation xml:lang="ru">
        <xsd:documentation>Description</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="field1" type="tns:NonEmptyString" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation xml:lang="ru">
                <xsd:documentation>Field1Description</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:group>
```

При этом проблемы начались только после того, как мы стали цепляться к этим полям. До этого они игнорировались сериализацией.

Уважаемые знатоки, вопрос следующий.
Что можно предпринять с нашей стороны, чтобы обеспечить нормальное взаимодействие с сервисом?

Comment: Используйте ShouldSerializeXXX, если я правильно понял вопрос: https://blog.jsinh.in/shouldserialize-conditional-xml-serialization-using-csharp/

Comment: Генерируются partial-классы? Добавьте второй partial-файл, где и определите `*Specified` или `ShouldSerialize*` - тогда они не будут "смываться" при перегенерации.

Comment: К сожалению ни один из вариантов не заработал.

Comment: А какие варианты вы пробовали?

Comment: Пробовали различные варианты инициализации полей, пробовали реализовать *Specified и ShouldSerialize*. Во всех вариантах теги оставались. Они пропадали только если полностью убрать все ссылки на эти проблемные поля.

Comment: Так же пытались шаманить с атрибутами XmlSerializer по спецификациям и методом научного тыка.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ваш вариант сработал, использование *Specified в partial классе решил нашу проблему. Оформите пожалуйста ваш комментарий как ответ, чтобы я мог оценить его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по результатам обсуждения в комментариях, можно прийти к выводу, что код классов генерируется автоматически. При этом к ним добавляется модификатор `partial`. Это позволяет вручную добавить файл(ы) с определением того же класса, в котором можно указать дополнительные члены.

В частности, для данного случая следует определить свойства `*Specified` или методы `ShouldSerialize*`, которые позволяет реализовать сериализацию полей по условию.

При перегенерации классов добавленные вручную файлы не будут затронуты: дополнительные свойства/методы останутся в неприкосновенности. Именно для этой цели автоматические генераторы кода (почти) всегда добавляют модификатор `partial`.